# Not getting child information after scrolling Grid view

Tags: android, gridview

I facing issue at time of scrolling grid view. In my grid view, total 150 child element are present and on screen total 55 childs are getting displayed.Now When user click on any grid then i need to change grid color to red,again i click on any other grid, then previous selected grid color change to white and newly clicked grid color change to red.So user get know which grid is currently selected. It's works perfect when user click on grid which are less than 55. but when user scrolled down grid view and click on any grid which is greater than 55, then i am not getting last selected grid due to this two red color grid are getting displayed.

Example :- first time If user click on 23 number grid then 23 number grid is selected but when user scroll down and select 63 number grid then i am not getting 23 number grid reference.flag also maintain for getting lastly selected grid.

```
 View currentchildAt = pizza_grid.getChildAt(currentGridNumber);
 currentchildAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 View childAt = pizza_grid.getChildAt(earlierGridNumber);

 if(childAt != null)
         childAt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

After selected 63 number grid i am getting `childAt`property null and if i checked `getChildCount()` then i am getting 55 count.

Can anyone please tell me how i can solve this problem.

I am using Adapter for display grid contain on grid view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, the selected option should bind to the item instead of simply the view showing, or I misunderstand the question
For example, simultaneously we can only show 30 items, when we clicked the 27th one, it does not mean when we scroll to 31 - 60, the 57th is in red. Therefore, I think it should be checked in getView() for the is number clicked or not in order to modify the view

Comment: Actually can we load all childs in grid view.right now only 30 childs is loaded and on scroll next element is loaded

Comment: Ys, but for adapter view, the views are assumed to be recycled and reused to other items while the items are not in visible state.

Comment: So how i can solve this issue. I need to display only one grid as selected(Red color).

Comment: In adapter class, just add an integer selectedPos = -1, and if once the item view is clicked, the related number is set to related item id, in getView, if currentItem id (instead of currentView number) showing equals to selectedPos, then show it red, else show it normal

Comment: Or you may provide your adapter class, i will simply make an example there